# Преобразование из string в логическое выражение

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как из переменной типа string получить переменную типа Boolean? Например, есть string s = "!a | b" и нужно преобразовать эту строку в логическое выражение типа:  Boolean y = !a | b.

Comment: гуглите [обратная польская нотация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)

Comment: А вариант скомпилировать на лету не рассматриваете?

Comment: А что в строке приходит? Валидное C#-выражение? Или выражение на каком-то другом языке?

Comment: Приходит валидное c#-выражение

Comment: А `a` и `b` откуда берутся?

Comment: С другой стороны, если выражение константное, то по какой причине это вообще строка?

Comment: Эта строка у меня изначально находится в файле (так по заданию), и после ее извлечения из файла мне нужно подставлять вместо a и b различные комбинации значений, например, а = 0 b = 0,  а = 1 b = 0...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно подключить из NuGet пакет [`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting) и скомпилировать из строки лямбду ([ссылка на ресурс](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/01/easy-way-to-create-a-c-lambda-expression-from-a-string-with-roslyn/)):

```
var expression = "!a | b";
var lambdaExpression = "(a, b) => " + expression;
var compiledExpression = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Func<bool, bool, bool>>(lambdaExpression).Result;
Console.WriteLine(compiledExpression(true, false));
```

Но у меня этот метод не заработал почему-то, поэтому я напишу как можно воспользоваться средой DLR и выполнить скрипт на IronPython.

Установите из NuGet пакет [`IronPython`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPython/), вместе с ним через зависимости подтянется также библиотека со средой DLR.

Пусть у нас имеется такое выражение на Python:

```
var pythonExpression = "not a or b";
```

Создадим "движок" питона:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
```

Получим из него рабочую область:

```
var scope = engine.CreateScope();
```

И добавим в нее входные переменные:

```
scope.SetVariable("a", true);
scope.SetVariable("b", false);
```

Склеим из выражения-функции выражение с присваиванием результата:

```
var pythonScript = "output = " + pythonExpression;
```

Запустим полученную строчку кода:

```
engine.Execute(pythonScript, scope);
```

И заберем из рабочей области результат:

```
var result = scope.GetVariable<bool>("output");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: (минусами не кидаюсь) вопрос прямой , самому интересен. а плюс поставил

Comment: Зачем писать парсер самому, если есть готовое решение, к тому же от самого MS. Если, конечно, у автора не учебное задание. А если учебное - пусть читает учебник/лекцию и выполняет :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP можно использовать `CSharpCodeProvider` и скомпилировать код в класс с методом на С#; Но у человека, кажется, задание на разбор строки :-/