# Как запустить скрипт python3 в C#?

Tags: c#, python-3.x, интеграция, ironpython

Читал про IronPython, но так и не понял, есть ли там полноценная поддержка python 3. Какими способами можно это сделать?

Comment: Python 2.7 там в текущей версии. Вот здесь простейший пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/815816/218063

Answer (score 0):

Поддержки Python 3.x в IronPython нет. Какое-то подобие статусу портирования можно посмотреть на странице [IronPython 3.x status and feature overview](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3/wiki/IronPython-3.x-status-and-feature-overview).

Сделать никак нельзя — если только вы не решите присоединиться к развитию IronPython сами.

Майкрософт забила на проект, а без поддержки он развивается медленно. Основной разраб сбежал.